# Use empty class(java)

Tags: java, design-patterns, uml

I m doing my best to speak in english to you, sorry for mistakes.

I have a school project about walmart's software.

My walmart has different sectors(food,technology,hygiene etc) and, products have also sectors ( an orange is food, a cd-rom is technology etc).

So i m going to create an abstract class sectors .and food , technology ,hygiene etc, will extends sectors.

BUT all their classes are empty: no field and methods, only extends stuff. So i m wondering if i should do it like that or this is awful.

Indeed i need, for example, a walmart that sell only food and technology, to know the products that are food or technology.

```
public class Walmart{
set<sector> sectors //can be for example only food, only technology or both
//field and methods
}

public class Product{
sector type
//field and methods
}
public abstract class Sector{//almost empty
}
public abstract class Food extends Sector{//also empty
}
public abstract class Technology extends Sector{//still empty}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. If you need any help you will need to code first and then ask a question about ay particular problem.

Comment: Have you already considered using an enum instead of subclasses as distinction? I think using empty subclasses is indeed questionable.

Comment: first note before reading any further: PLEASE start class names with upper case characters.

Comment: I don't understand : "Indeed i need, for example, a walmart that sell only food and technology, to know the products that are food or technology."

Comment: You should move this to the code review site.
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: From what I can gather, I would only have Company, Product and Sector as classes. Remember classes are generic types - so even Walmart would an instance (enum, db value, etc.). Similarly food, technology, etc. should be either enums or db value objects.

Comment: I didn't copy / paste , and forgot about Uppercase, sorry.

As you don't understand  i will try to reformulate:

-My problem is more about pattern 

-I have classes that are empty, and i use them only for their types.And i m wondering if it's bad to do like that, and checking if there are better idea  

-@mm759 i m gonna to check about enum , thanks

Comment: It's fine to use empty classes, to distinguish objects that have the same structure, but a different meaning. The compiler can give an error, e.g. if you try to assign an instance of Food to a variable of type Technology.